# Flutter SQFLite How to Save Single Note

Tags: flutter, sqflite

I am using Flutter to save a single note on a page.

Issue: I don't understand how to implement saving and retrieving a note on a page.

Most Flutter note examples are based on a list of notes using Future List.

I need to save a single note. Please see my code below.

Could you please advise how to fix the code for a single note: createNote,UpdateNote, and DeleteNote.

Thank You

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:path/path.dart';
import 'package:sqflite/sqflite.dart';

final String myNoteTable = 'myNote';

class NoteFields {
  static final List<String> values = [id,myNote,];
  static final String id = '_id'; // SQL convention
  static final String myNote = 'myNote';
}

class Note {
  final int? id;
  late String myText;

  Note({required this.id,required this.myText,});
  Note copy({int? id,String? myNote}) => Note(id: id ?? this.id,myText: myText ?? this.myText,);
  Map<String, Object?> toJson() => {NoteFields.id: id,NoteFields.myNote: myText,};
  static Note fromJson(Map<String, Object?> json) => Note(id: json[NoteFields.id] as int?,myText: json[NoteFields.myNote] as String);
}

class DB {
  static const String myDatabase = 'myDatabase.db';

  DB._init(); // private constructor
  static final DB instance = DB._init();
  static Database? database;

  // Open Database
  Future<Database> get dataBase async {
    if (database != null) {return database!;} else {
      database = await initDB(myDatabase);
      return database!;
    }
  }

  Future<Database> initDB(String filePath) async {
    final dbPath = await getDatabasesPath();
    final path = join(dbPath, filePath);
    return await openDatabase(path, version: 1, onCreate: createDB);
  }

  Future createDB(Database db, int version) async {
    var idType = 'INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT';
    var textType = 'TEXT NOT NULL';
    await db.execute('''CREATE TABLE $myNoteTable(${NoteFields.id} $idType,${NoteFields.myNote} $textType)''');
  }

  Future<Note> createNote(Note note) async {
    final db = await instance.dataBase;
    final id = await db.insert(conflictAlgorithm: ConflictAlgorithm.replace,myNoteTable,note.toJson());
    return note.copy(id: id);
  }

  Future<List<Note>> readNote() async {
    final db = await instance.dataBase;
    final result = await db.rawQuery('SELECT * FROM $myNoteTable');
    final list = result.map((json) => Note.fromJson(json)).toList();
    if(list.isNotEmpty) return list; else throw Exception('Empty List');
  }

  Future<int> updateNote(Note note) async {
    final db = await instance.dataBase;
    return db.update(myNoteTable,note.toJson(),where: '${NoteFields.id} = ?',whereArgs: [note.id]);
  }

  Future<int> deleteNote(int id) async {
    final db = await instance.dataBase;
    return await db.delete(myNoteTable,where: '${NoteFields.id} = ?',whereArgs: [id]);
  }

  Future close() async {
    final db = await instance.dataBase;
    db.close();
  }
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  final int? taskId;
  const MyApp({Key? key, this.taskId});
  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => MyAppState();
}

class MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  double myfontsize = 9.0;
  static final TextEditingController myNote = TextEditingController();
  static final scrollController = ScrollController();

  @override
  void initState() {
    refreshNote();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    myNote.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  saveNote(){
    if (myNote.text.isNotEmpty) {
      setState(() {
        DB.instance.createNote();
      });
    }
  }

  updateNote(){
    if (myNote.text.isNotEmpty) {
      setState(() {
        DB.instance.updateNote();
      });
    }
  }

  refreshNote(){
    if (myNote.text.isNotEmpty) {
      setState(() {
        DB.instance.readNote();
      });
    }
  }

  deleteNote(){
    if (myNote.text.isNotEmpty) {
      setState(() {
        DB.instance.deleteNote();
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Widget space = SizedBox(width: 1000, height: 5, child: Text(""));
    Widget userNote = SizedBox(width: 1000,height: 80,child: TextField(maxLines: 10,scrollController: scrollController,decoration: InputDecoration(border: OutlineInputBorder()),controller: myNote));
    Widget myButtons = SizedBox(width: 1000,height: 30,child: Row(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: [
          Expanded(child: TextButton(onPressed: saveNote,style: TextButton.styleFrom(backgroundColor: Colors.blue,side: BorderSide(width: 1.0)),child: Text("Save",style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: myfontsize)))),
          Expanded(child: TextButton(onPressed: updateNote,style: TextButton.styleFrom(backgroundColor: Colors.blue,side: BorderSide(width: 1.0)),child: Text("Update",style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: myfontsize)))),
          Expanded(child: TextButton(onPressed: deleteNote,style: TextButton.styleFrom(backgroundColor: Colors.blue,side: BorderSide(width: 1.0)),child: Text("Delete",style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: myfontsize)))),
        ]));
      return MaterialApp(home: Scaffold(resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,appBar: AppBar(),body: Container(padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5),child: SingleChildScrollView(child: Column(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              children: <Widget>[space,userNote,space,myButtons,space])))));

  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

### Explanation

What is implemented right now is (as you said) a list of notes.

If you only want to save a single note, using sqflite would probably be too much for it.
As a simple explanation: SQL is a language for interacting with databases. Oversimplified, you only need a database when you have data with internal dependencies (for example a user table and a post table that need to be connected) or need to store large quantities of data.

### Simple solution

In your case, you only have one data piece, so using a [plain text file](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/persistence/reading-writing-files) is fine.

### Complex solution

If you really want to use a database, following untested solution should work:

```dart
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:path/path.dart';
import 'package:sqflite/sqflite.dart';

import 'package:sqflite_common_ffi/sqflite_ffi.dart'; // if you build a desktop application

class DB {
  DB._create(); // disable default constructor

  // the underscore makes the database private
  late final Database _database;

  Future<void> _asyncInit() async { // opens the database file
    String dbPath = await getDatabasesPath();
    dbPath = join(dbPath, 'notes.db');

    // run on the desktop:
    if (Platform.isWindows || Platform.isLinux) {
      sqfliteFfiInit();
      databaseFactory = databaseFactoryFfi;
    }

    _database = await openDatabase(
      dbPath,
      onCreate: (Database db, int version) async {
        // create the table directly, this avoids confusion. and searching for more variable definitions
        // The table has 2 columns one with an id and one with the text. The id is the PRIMARY KEY, which means that
        // each id can only be in the table once.
        await db.execute('CREATE TABLE myNote(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, text STRING)');
      },
      version: 1,
    );
  }

  static Future<DB> open() async {
    final instance = DB._create();
    await instance._asyncInit();
    return instance;
  }

  /// Gets the text saved in the database. [id] is an optional argument, that becoms useful, once you decide to
  /// handle multiple notes.
  Future<String> getNote([int id = 0]) async {
    final List<Map<String, Object?>> queryResult = await _database.query(
        'myNote', // table name
        columns: ['text'], // This means the map in the queryResult list will have the key 'text'
        where: 'id = ?', // here we don't insert id directly into the string, but use arguments. The '?' will get replaced
        whereArgs: [id] // with the element in the whereArgs list. This is a cleaner style but nothing for you to bother about.
    );

    // There are 2 cases we need to consider:
    // a) There is no note with the id saved, in this case the list will be empty
    if (queryResult.isEmpty) {
      return ''; // return empty note
    }
    // b) There is a note saved, in this case the list will have one item
    return queryResult.first.toString();
    // More entries can not occur as id is our PRIMARY KEY.

    // a shorter way to write this would be:
    // `return queryResult.firstOrNull?.toString() ?? '';`
  }

  Future<void> saveNote(String text, [int id = 0]) async {
    await _database.insert(
        'myNote', // table name
        { // table with column names and the value in the inserted row
          'id': id,
          'text': text,
        },
        // because we have PRIMARY KEY at our id column, this will automatically handle the case that there already is a
        // value.
        conflictAlgorithm: ConflictAlgorithm.replace
    );
  }
}
```

You would use it like this:

```
void main() async {
  final db = await DB.open();
  await db.saveNote('derdilla');
  print(await db.getNote()); // > derdilla
}
```

Comment: I am confused about what I have, and this is not a solution I am trying to find. I need to use SQFLite database. Could you please revise the code for SQLite if possible.

Comment: @DktPhl2018 I added a second solution with an example of how to use sqflte for this task.